# jQuery .load(); not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my first time trying this.

I have the following code in the head of an **ajax.html**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $( "#result" ).load( "/loaded.html" );
});
```

Then in the same directory, I have a second page, **loaded.html:**

```
<div id="result">Hello!</div>
```

However `#result` is not loaded. I have double checked jQuery, and it's all plugged in.

Would anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `/`, run your code from FF (instead Chrome) or from `localhost`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
$("selector to load into").load("loaded.html #result");
```

You apply `.load()` to the DIV you want to load into. If you want to search in the loaded data for a specific DIV, put that selector after the URL.

And since you're loading from the same directory, don't put `/` at the beginning of the URL. That means to load from the webroot directory.

Comment: Thanks, still not loading though.

Comment: Hmm. How do I tell which div to load it into? At the moment, I thought I was saying find `#result` within `loaded.html`?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't quite understand the premise of it.